# Django 1.6.5 - 404 error with static files

Tags: django

I know there are other questions similar to mine, but I've tried everything to get my static files working and need some help. When I open my page I get these errors:

```
GET /static/css/cerulean/css HTTP/1.1" 404 2983
GET /static/js/bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1 404 2980
```

This is my project directory (most files ommitted):

```
Motif_Django
   Motif_Django
      settings.py
      urls.py
   motif
   static
      css
         cerulean.css
      js
         bootstrap.js
```

Here are the important settings in `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/kimberly/Motif-Scan-Plus/Motif_Django/static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   '/home/kimberly/Motif-Scan-Plus/Motif_Django/static',
   '/home/kimberly/Motif-Scan-Plus/Motif_Django/motif/static/motif/',
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',)
```

Under `INSTALLED_APPS` I have included `django.contrib.staticfiles`. The `STATIC_ROOT` folder was initially empty and I collected static files with `python manage.py collectstatic` and I still get these errors. In my HTML form I am using `{% load staticfiles %}` and trying to load it with 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/cerulean.css' %}` but nothing is working. I included the full URL in `STATIC_URL` to see if that would help, as well as adding the full path of my static folder in  `STATICFILES_DIRS` but still nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

- `STATIC_URL` is not supposed to be absolute URL, just the path (ie. `/static/`).
- `settings.DEBUG` has to be `True`
- You have to serve `static()` url patterns in `urls.py`

.

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... patterns,
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Check related guide in Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: Thanks!! Switching the `STATIC_URL` and changing the `urls.py` (I originally had staticfiles_urlpatterns() ) did the trick!!

Comment: In DEBUG mode you don't need to `collectstatic` or add static to urls. In DEBUG mode statics are served by `runserver` from application static directories.